# Reshape list levels by group

Tags: r, list, subset, purrr

I have a large list with four data frame elements of varying structure. Each data frame has an ID variable that can be listed multiple times.

Below is a simpler version of what my list looks like.

```
set.seed(123) 

fruit <- data.frame(
  id = rep(1:10, 3),
  crop = rep(c("apple", "pear", "banana"), each = 10),
  consumed = sample(0:20, 30, replace=TRUE),
  sold = sample(1:10, 30, replace = TRUE))

veg <- data.frame(
  id = rep(1:10, 2),
  crop = rep(c("potatoe", "onion"), each = 10),
  consumed = sample(0:20, 20, replace=TRUE),
  gifted = sample(0:10, 20, replace=TRUE)
)

milk <- data.frame(
  id = 1:10,
  item = "milk",
  consumed = sample(1:6, 10, replace = T),
  produced  = sample(1:20, 10, replace = T),
  processed = sample(0.5:3.5, 10, replace = T),
  sold = sample(0.5:3.5, 10, replace = T))

food <- list(fruit, veg, milk)

food
```

I would like to either split the list by ID where ID is the first level and fruit, veg and milk become the second level or find another way to group by ID across list elements. Basically, I want everything for one particular ID in one place to apply a function I have written that summarises all data for that particular ID.

I tried a few map options.

Comment: Can you please provide the desired output for this sample input so that possible solutions can be tested and verified?

Comment: You wnat this? `library(dplyr) food %>% 
  bind_rows() %>% 
  group_split(id)`

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option that uses `tidyr::nest()` and then `purrr::reduce()` to create a data frame that has one row for each `id`, and the `milk`, `fruit`, and `veg` frames nested in the columnns:

```
names(food) <- c("fruit", "veg", "milk")

lapply(names(food), \(f) nest(food[[f]], .by=id,.key =f )) %>%
  reduce(full_join, by="id")
```

Output:

```
      id fruit            veg              milk            
   <int> <list>           <list>           <list>          
 1     1 <tibble [3 × 3]> <tibble [2 × 3]> <tibble [1 × 5]>
 2     2 <tibble [3 × 3]> <tibble [2 × 3]> <tibble [1 × 5]>
 3     3 <tibble [3 × 3]> <tibble [2 × 3]> <tibble [1 × 5]>
 4     4 <tibble [3 × 3]> <tibble [2 × 3]> <tibble [1 × 5]>
 5     5 <tibble [3 × 3]> <tibble [2 × 3]> <tibble [1 × 5]>
 6     6 <tibble [3 × 3]> <tibble [2 × 3]> <tibble [1 × 5]>
 7     7 <tibble [3 × 3]> <tibble [2 × 3]> <tibble [1 × 5]>
 8     8 <tibble [3 × 3]> <tibble [2 × 3]> <tibble [1 × 5]>
 9     9 <tibble [3 × 3]> <tibble [2 × 3]> <tibble [1 × 5]>
10    10 <tibble [3 × 3]> <tibble [2 × 3]> <tibble [1 × 5]>
```

Comment: That's very helpful and probably what I am looking for. How do I get from a nested data frame to a nested list though?
So ID is the first level and the foods are nested as lists?
$`1`
$`1`$`fruit`
$`1`$`veg`
$`1`$`milk`
$`2`
$`2`$`fruit`
$`2`$`veg`
$`2`$`milk` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are after this?

```
lst <- unlist(lapply(food, split, ~id), recursive = FALSE)

split(lst, names(lst))
```

which gives

```
$`1`
$`1`$`1`
   id   crop consumed sold
1   1  apple       14    9
11  1   pear        4    5
21  1 banana       13    4

$`1`$`1`
   id    crop consumed gifted
1   1 potatoe        1      2
11  1   onion       11      2

$`1`$`1`
  id item consumed produced processed sold
1  1 milk        6       14       2.5  3.5


$`10`
$`10`$`10`
   id   crop consumed sold
10 10  apple       13    2
20 10   pear        3   10
30 10 banana        6    1

$`10`$`10`
   id    crop consumed gifted
10 10 potatoe       15      5
20 10   onion        7      9

$`10`$`10`
   id item consumed produced processed sold
10 10 milk        4       20       3.5  3.5


$`2`
$`2`$`2`
   id   crop consumed sold
2   2  apple       18    9
12  2   pear       18    8
22  2 banana       16    6

$`2`$`2`
   id    crop consumed gifted
2   2 potatoe        3      9
12  2   onion       13      7

$`2`$`2`
  id item consumed produced processed sold
2  2 milk        6       19       2.5  1.5


$`3`
$`3`$`3`
   id   crop consumed sold
3   3  apple       13   10
13  3   pear        8    2
23  3 banana       10    8

$`3`$`3`
   id    crop consumed gifted
3   3 potatoe       12      1
13  3   onion        2      2

$`3`$`3`
  id item consumed produced processed sold
3  3 milk        3        7       3.5  2.5


$`4`
$`4`$`4`
   id   crop consumed sold
4   4  apple        2    7
14  4   pear        2    1
24  4 banana        6    6

$`4`$`4`
   id    crop consumed gifted
4   4 potatoe        4      9
14  4   onion       13      7

$`4`$`4`
  id item consumed produced processed sold
4  4 milk        2        9       0.5  3.5


$`5`
$`5`$`5`
   id   crop consumed sold
5   5  apple        9    5
15  5   pear        7    9
25  5 banana       20    6

$`5`$`5`
   id    crop consumed gifted
5   5 potatoe       18      1
15  5   onion        6      0

$`5`$`5`
  id item consumed produced processed sold
5  5 milk        5        7       3.5  3.5


$`6`
$`6`$`6`
   id   crop consumed sold
6   6  apple       17    7
16  6   pear        6    9
26  6 banana       11    7

$`6`$`6`
   id    crop consumed gifted
6   6 potatoe       19      9
16  6   onion        2      6

$`6`$`6`
  id item consumed produced processed sold
6  6 milk        6        2       1.5  3.5


$`7`
$`7`$`7`
   id   crop consumed sold
7   7  apple       10    5
17  7   pear        9    6
27  7 banana       14    1

$`7`$`7`
   id    crop consumed gifted
7   7 potatoe       13      5
17  7   onion       14     10

$`7`$`7`
  id item consumed produced processed sold
7  7 milk        5       16       1.5  2.5


$`8`
$`8`$`8`
   id   crop consumed sold
8   8  apple        4    6
18  8   pear        8    5
28  8 banana        9    6

$`8`$`8`
   id    crop consumed gifted
8   8 potatoe        2      3
18  8   onion       20      6

$`8`$`8`
  id item consumed produced processed sold
8  8 milk        3       13       3.5  0.5


$`9`
$`9`$`9`
   id   crop consumed sold
9   9  apple       19    9
19  9   pear       18    9
29  9 banana       12    2

$`9`$`9`
   id    crop consumed gifted
9   9 potatoe        7      0
19  9   onion        4      6

$`9`$`9`
  id item consumed produced processed sold
9  9 milk        4       19       0.5  3.5
```